# Yii queryScalar works but queryAll causes white page

Tags: mysql, database, activerecord, yii, findall

I am using the following code to grab all records from a table:

```
$signups = Yii::app()->db
->createCommand("SELECT ID FROM signup WHERE `MEMBERSHIP_NO` IS NOT NULL")
->queryScalar();
```

Which returns 1.

When I use:

```
$signups = Yii::app()->db
->createCommand("SELECT ID FROM signup WHERE `MEMBERSHIP_NO` IS NOT NULL")
->queryAll();
```

A white page is shown with no exception.

Same applies for:

```
Signup::model()->findAll('`MEMBERSHIP_NO` IS NOT NULL')
```

Comment: See if you find anything in your `/runtime/appilication.log` and your apaches `error.log`. Check your php.ini if `error_reporting` and `display_errors` are actually set to report errors.

Comment: It won't reach any code below the query line. It seems to stop execution then. I dont see any syntax errors, and running the same SQL on the database directly (through phpMyAdmin for example), it works fine. Could it be that there are over 160,000 records in the table?

Comment: I have the same issue, did you ever fix this?